# How do I transform this function into something better like a loop?

Tags: c, function, loops, cs50

So my problem is in [problem set 1](https://docs.cs50.net/problems/cash/cash.html#walkthrough) of week 1 of the CS50 Harvard course. The task was writing a program that calculates the smallest amount of coins possible when getting change. I've already written the program and it works, but I wanted to know if any of you can tell me how to further improve my function that calculates the amount of coins. It is basically the same lines of code copied and pasted 4 times and just changing the coin value inside of it (25, 10, 5, 1). Can anyone help me transform this into some sort of loop, since although copying & pasting works it feels kind of bad to look at for me.

```
int calculate_coins(int change)
{
    //Count coins from 0
    int n = 0;

    //How much 25s can be used? 
    n += change / 25;
    //Calculate remaining change
    change %= 25;

    n += change / 10;
    change %= 10;

    n += change / 5;
    change %= 5;

    n += change / 1;
    change %= 1;

    return n;
}
```

Comment: There's a [cs50 stack exchange](https://cs50.stackexchange.com/) if you're interested.

Comment: @pmg Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have made the array as global in case I would like to use it anywhere else. Other than that I agree.

```
int value[] = { 25, 10, 5, 1 }; //global array

int calculate_coins(int change)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
    {
        n += change / value[i];
        change %= value[i];
    }

    return n;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what kind of code youre using and why? Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Using a loop to group similar code as you requested. The difference between the similar lines of code is just a value; so I put the values in an array and loop through those values sequentially.